# How to get valid/invalid login from OAuth 2 for Ruby

Tags: ruby, authentication, oauth-2.0, restforce

I'm running the Restforce API, which I believe uses OAuth 2 from what I have read.  The login I have works, but at this point I am just trying to make something that returns whether the login was successful or not.  I have the username, password, security token, client id, and client secret.

When I print the result it returns:

```
#Restforce::Data::Client:0x0055b1b3433798
```

Is there a way I can have it return "success!" or "failure!" or anything like that?

```
URI_SF = URI.parse(URI.encode("https://na35.salesforce.com"))

def use_restforce_api()
    rf_client = Restforce.new(username: EMAIL,
                       password: PASSWORD,
                       security_token: SECURITY_TOKEN,
                       instance_url: URI_SF,
                       client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                       client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
                       api_version: '38.0')

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out by going through the documentation.  It was:

```
info = rf_client.get(response.id).body
puts info
```

On success it returns information where I can access every bit with `info.username`, `info.object`.

On failure of `client_id` and `client_secret`, they each give their own respective messages.  On failure of the username, security token, or API key, it gives the same failure message.

I can work with that.